# Dropbox Windows App - How Do You Make The Pop-Up Smaller

Tags: windows-10, dropbox

The Dropbox app on my Windows 10 machine just updated.  I noticed that when I open the pop-up using the icon on the bottom right hand side of the screen, the updated pop-up is much bigger than the old pop-up.  The new pop-up looks like:

[image]

Is there anyway to resize this pop-up / make it smaller?

Comment: Which version of the Dropbox application do you have.  Dropbox recently introduced a new version of the client that is more like OneDrive.

Comment: [It certainly looks like you opted into the early access program for Dropbox.](https://blog.dropbox.com/topics/product-tips/new-dropbox)